# vScrollBar / hScrollBar - BackColor and other properties

Tags: c#, properties, scrollbar

I'm trying to customize the look of my form. It looked like it would be easier to replace a control's scrollbar rather than repaint it on each control. The online documentation say BackColor is a property of vScrollBar and hScrollBar, but BackColor is missing in the IDE. And BackColor does not come up as an auto-complete options. But you can force property and it will compile, but not change the BackColor of the control.

Is there an easy way to customize the scrollbar?

```
    Color backgroundDark = Color.FromArgb(50, 50, 50);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BackColor = backgroundDark;

        VScrollBar vScrollBar1 = new VScrollBar();
        vScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        vScrollBar1.BackColor = backgroundDark; //<----------here
        Controls.Add(vScrollBar1);
    }
```

Comment: `VScrollBar` inherits from `Control` which is where `BackColor` is declared. So technically all controls have a BackColor property, even where it can't be used.